# How to query all content from a field in Elasticssearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm queriying data from Elasticsearch with python. I can query a certain value in a field like this:

```
GET index/_search
{
   "query": {
        "match" : {
            "somefieldname": "somevalue" 
        }
    }
}
```

But how can I query all values inside the field `somefieldname`?

UPDATE:

Here's an example index:

```
"_index" : „indexname
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "lJlcO3wBhlKWxmXE9jrd",
        "_score" : 0,  
"_source": {
    „field1“: „abc“,
    „field2“: „123",
    „field3": „def“,
   
  },
"_index" : „indexname
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "lJlcO3wBhlKWxmXE9jrd",
        "_score" : 0,  
  "_source": {
    „field1“: „fgh“,
    „field2“: „654",
    „field3": „kui“,
   
  },
"_index" : „indexname
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "lJlcO3wBhlKWxmXE9jrd",
        "_score" : 00,  
  "_source": {
    „field1“: „567“,
    „field2“: „gfr",
    „field3": „234“,
   
  },
```

Now I want to query all content from field2 from all docs. So that my output is `[„123", „654", „gfr"]`

UPDATE:

Index mapping for the field:

```
{
  "myindex" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "field2" : {
        "full_name" : "field2",
        "mapping" : {
          "field2" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain your use case with an example ?

Comment: I'm querying data with python and I simply need all (unique) values within this field from all docs. Actually something very simple. I tried it with a "*" wildcard but it doesn't work. The filtering for unique values can be done in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html), to get unique values from `field2`

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "field2values": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "field2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result would be

```
"aggregations": {
    "field2values": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "123",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "654",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "gfr",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: @stanvooz please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: I get `"buckets" : [ ]`

Comment: @stanvooz can you please share your index mapping for `field2` ?

Comment: ok done, please check orig. question

Comment: @stanvooz which version of elasticsearch are you using ? The structure of mapping is not correct, can you please run this `GET /<index-name>/_mapping`, to get the index mapping ?

Comment: 7.10(AWS version). It hink I can't post the entire index, my question is a simplified extraction. What's wrong with the structure? It's the output of `GET /myindex_mapping/field/field2`

Comment: @stanvooz There is no issue with the mapping, since you have defined `field2` of `keyword` type, you need to use `"terms": {
        "field": "field2"
      }`. I have updated the query, please try with the updated query and let me know if this resolves your issue?